# Wicket Rich Text Editor

Tags: wicket

I am stuck!!! There's an application I'm doing in wicket which requires the use of a rich text editor. I managed to use the visural rte and i am storing data from the rte to the database(the data stores with html tags generated within the RTE). When I retrieve the data, I can render it well in the RTE, by setting DefaultModelObject. My  problem is, I want to make this RTE readonly programmatically based on some conditions but I can't. I have a feeling this visural rte does not conform to the basic wicket functionality like setenabled etc and I am getting frustrated. I opted to get the data and render it using multiline label but it displays everything plus the html tags. Can someone assist me out of this?? If i can make the rte readonly programmatically, I will be sorted!

Comment: I'm not familiar with the component, but how do you normally make it read-only using javascript?

Answer (score 2):

The default behaviour is to escape output coming from your model data, as a protection against cross-site scripting, but you can change this selectively.

Something resembling

```
multilineLabel.setEscapeModelStrings(false)
```

should make your multiline label solution display rendered html instead of what you're currently seeing.

Comment: +1, although if your data is html anyway, you don't need a multiline label, a plain label is better.

Comment: @biziclop - Yes, a plain label should be fine for this.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Don. I will do this and see how it goes. I will post what I find out here.

Comment: setEscapeModelStrings(false) actually did the trick. @biziclop, a Label was best for my situation. The data rendered well. 
I just want to mention that even appending javascript to the visural rte could not make it readonly. I am glad my plan (using label to display the data) worked.